# What is the measure of $x \in [0.1]$ whose binary representations have percentage of ones that converge within a given range?

Tags: measure-theory

For binary representation of $x \in [0,1]$, i.e. $x = \sum_n a_n 2^{-n}$, (where all $a_n$ are binary, and using all trailing ones is chosen instead of rounding up), let $X(b,c) \subset [0,1]$ be the set of all numbers $x$ which satisfy $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^n a_j/n = \alpha$ where $b \leq \alpha \leq c$. What is the measure of $X(b,c)$ if $b=c$? What if $b < c$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the law of large numbers the set $X(b,c)$ has Lebesgue measure $1$ when $b\leqslant\frac12\leqslant c$ and Lebesgue measure $0$ otherwise.

The idea is that if $x$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$ then $(a_n)$ is a sequence of independent Bernoulli random variables such that $P[a_n=0]=P[a_n=1]=\frac12$. Hence $\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^na_k\to E[a_1]$ almost surely when $n\to\infty$. Since $E[a_1]=\frac12\cdot0+\frac12\cdot1=\frac12$, the result above follows.

Comment: I have no idea how to see that :)

Comment: See expanded version.